# Get private key from file in Python

Tags: python, private-key, bitcoin

I've been working with [pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) for a while and I'm not sure exactly how to properly manage with private key loading in order to sign transactions.

```
def sign(tx, i, priv, hashcode=SIGHASH_ALL): ...
```

The sign function requires a key as a str that is used to perform the signature, but if you want to import that keys from a key file there's no way to export the private key as a str (or at least I've not been able to find it).

Some time ago I created a small OpenSSL wrapper in Python in order to load the key and extract the private part, but I don't think it is the most correct way and definitely not the most elegant one.

Does anyone know if there's any proper way to do it?

Maybe the question is quite odd, but I would like to be sure I was not being using it wrong all this time.

Comment: You say "key file", what format is the key in? Can you give an example of the type of private key file you want to use?

Comment: In my case, I'm referring to a  .pem file created using M2Crypto python's library.

`# Generate the elliptic curve and the keys
`ec = EC.gen_params(EC.NID_secp256k1)
`ec.gen_key()
`# Generate a Pkey object to store the EC keys
`mem = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
`ec.save_pub_key_bio(mem)
`ec.save_key_bio(mem, None)

Comment: I can't place code properly in the comment, I hope you get my point.